# What's the difference between a pointer, and a pointer variable?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I know this is very basic but it is little bit confusing to me.
I've read:

> a **pointer** is nothing more than an **address**, and a **pointer variable** is just a variable that can **store an address**.
>   When we store the address of a variable `i` in the pointer variable `p`, we say that `p` **points to** `i`.

```
int i, *p = &i;
```

`p` points to `i`.

To gain access to the object that a pointer points to, we use the `*` (indirection) operator.

> If `p` **is a pointer** then `*p` represents the object to which `p` currently points.

Now I am confused that what should I call `p` --  **pointer** or **pointer variable**?

Additional: ***Is a pointer always the same as an address?***

Comment: reading ["What does “dereferencing” a pointer mean?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) may be helpful and of-course from wiki: ["Pointer (computer programming)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming))

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; I have read the first link befor asking this question :). Thanks for the second link.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Thanks for the wiki link. It explain dereferencing in a very beautiful way.(actually it has been my next question if you have not provided that link :) ).

Comment: Usually it's a good idea (at least as a beginner) to split these type of declarations up into multiple lines. That is `int i, *p = &i;` is equivalent to `int i;` `int *p = &i;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between a pointer value and a pointer variable is illustrated by:

```
int swap_int(int *i1, int *i2)
{
    int t = *i1;
    *i1 = *i2;
    *i2 = t;
}

int main(void)
{
    int  v1 = 0;
    int  v2 = 37;
    int *p2 = &v2;
    printf("v1 = %d, v2 = %d\n", v1, v2);
    swap_int(&v1, p2);
    printf("v1 = %d, v2 = %d\n", v1, v2);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `p2` is a pointer variable; it is a pointer to `int`.  On the other hand, in the call to `swap_int()`, the argument `&v1` is a pointer value, but it is in no sense a pointer variable (in the calling function).  It is a pointer to a variable (and that variable is `v1`), but simply writing `&v1` is not creating a pointer variable.  Inside the called function, the value of the pointer `&v1` is assigned to the local pointer variable `i1`, and the value of the pointer variable `p2` is assigned to the local pointer variable `i2`, but that's not the same as saying `&v1` is a pointer variable (because it isn't a pointer variable; it is simply a pointer value).

However, for many purposes, the distinction is blurred.  People would say '`p2` is a pointer' and that's true enough; it is a pointer variable, and its value is a pointer value, and `*p2` is the value of the object that `p2` points to.  You get the same blurring with '`v1` is an `int`'; it is actually an `int` variable and its value is an `int` value.

Comment: And AFAIK the Standard doesn't even use the terminology "variable" anyway.

Comment: @haccks No, when I write "variable", I mean "variable".

Comment: @H2CO3; Then what terminology used in standard for memory address?

Comment: @haccks "pointer-to-T", where "T" is a type. And "objects" are used for variables IIRC, but you can check the current or previous C standard (C11 and C99, respectively), they're available for free on the Internet.

Comment: @h2co3; Hmmm. So it is better to say *pointer to type* instead * pointer to variable/object* right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33453/discussion-between-h2co3-and-haccks)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler; And also: **Is a pointer always the same as an address?**

Comment: I'd say 'yes: a valid pointer is always the address of some object or function; a null pointer is invalid but recognizable; other invalid pointers are dangerous to use — even reading them without dereferencing them might cause problems on some (mainly mainframe-like) systems'.

Comment: @H2CO3: In section §5.1.2.3, some non-normative (example) text says _the abstract machine [must] promote the value of each variable to `int` size
and then add the two `int`s and truncate the sum._  There are a few other non-normative references to variables in section 6 (the main definition of the language), but the main spiel manages to avoid the term variable except for variable length arrays and variable argument lists, neither of which counts.

Comment: In the example you have given, you assigned address of `v1` to `p`, shouldn't it be address of `v2` as we are swapping `v1` and `v2`?

Comment: Yes; I'll fix that, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, alright. That's basically what I thought. (I didn't insist that the whole document didn't contain the word at all, just that the core standard text doesn't use it for describing those things with names, types and values.)

Answer (score 8):

Let's replace the word "pointer" with a datatype that's hopefully more familiar, like an `int`:

```
int n = 42;
```

Here 42 is an `int` value, and `n` is a variable that holds an `int`. You could call `n` an "`int` variable". An int is a number like 42 or  -25315685, and an `int` variable holds these numbers. Once you have a variable you can assign different numbers to it. Nothing confusing so far?

A *pointer* is just like an int: a number. It happens to be a number that identifies a memory location, and if something is stored in that memory location you can call it an *address*. Like an int, a pointer can be stored in a variable. A variable that stores a pointer could be called a pointer variable.

So, **what's the difference between a pointer  and a pointer variable?** The first one is a value, like a number, the second stores these values. But often people refer to variables by their values that they store; people don't call `n` an "`int` variable" but just `int`, even though it can at different times store different `int`s. In this text I'll do the same and sometimes write pointer when I mean a pointer variable; hopefully the distinction will be clear.

**Is a pointer always an address?** This is a question about the meaning of the word "address" more than anything else. A pointer is always an address in the sense that it corresponds to a memory location in one way or another, it's an "address" for that memory location. But on the other hand, if the memory location is not accessible to the program or doesn't have anything useful stored in it, is it really an "address" for anything?

Let's now investigate the following code:

```
int *p;
p = &n;
```

The first line declares a pointer variable called `p`. The pointers that can be stored into `p` are memory locations for `int` data; this is important for reasons that we'll see later. We still don't give `p` any value, so the pointer it stores is arbitrary. It certainly doesn't store the address of anything useful; it may even point to an area of memory inaccessible to the program.

In the second line we take the address of the `n` variable with the `&`-operator and assign it to `p`. Now `p` stores the address of `n`, the memory location where the value of `n` is stored.

What can we do with a pointer? We can read and write to the memory location that the pointer identifies. To do this we "dereference" the pointer with the `*`-operator, and then `(*p)` can be used just like you can use `n`. For example, you can write a new value into `n` with this:

```
*p = 123;
```

It's at this point that it becomes apparent why we need to know the type of data that `p` can point to: otherwise you can't know what you could assign to `(*p)`.

Another reason why it's important to know the type of data that `p` can point to is *pointer arithmetic*. For example `p+1` is a pointer to the `int` stored in memory right after `n`; if `p` was a pointer to a big data structure `p+1` would be a pointer to a data structure of the same type stored right after it. For this the compiler must know the size of what the pointer points to.

Comment: Thanks for explaining additional one( but I did't get your explanation completely) +1.

Comment: What parts did you find difficult to follow?

Comment: Your investigation part is really good and it helped me understand some good points but it is not specific to my question; **Is a pointer always an address?**

Comment: Well, that would depend on what's meant by "address" but I would say no. Imagine you're writing a program for a modern computer: the program asks the operating system for some memory. The only valid addresses are for the memory the OS returned, but there are many more values you can store in a pointer. Or imagine an embedded system without an operating system. The only valid addresses are for the memory that's actually installed, which is typically a fraction of the number of distinct pointer values. A pointer is not always a valid address.

Answer (score 2):

The token `p` is a pointer variable, that points to a variable `i`. We can simply call it a pointer.

A declaration:

```
int* p;
int i;
p = &i;
```

declares `p` as the identifier of an `int` type object. This is usually stated more succinctly as `'p is a pointer to i'`.  `p` can be used to refer int variable `i` after expression `p = &i`. To access the value of variable `i` using pointer `p` you can use the dereference operator `*` (e.g. `*p`). And `i = 10;` equivalent to `*p = 10;`.

Also, notice in expression `p = &i;` to read the address of `i` I used `&` ampersand operator also called `Address of operand`.

A pointer is just a logical address (an identifier by which a variable can be referenced). The C standard does not define what a pointer is internally and how it works internally.

You would like to read: [What exactly is a C pointer if not a memory address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151377/what-exactly-is-a-c-pointer-if-not-a-memory-address/15151542#15151542)
Additionally, read this: [to Understand the purpose of pointers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642074/understanding-the-purpose-of-pointers/17642125#17642125)

Comment: But it is said that **a pointer is nothing more than an address**

Comment: Yes. Give me a moment , I am going through it.

Comment: @haccks your welcome, yes Jonathon is awesome guy! I read many of his answers.

Answer (score 0):

The terms pointer and pointer variable are often used synonymously.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is a place to store a value.  In C, whenever you use a variable in a context that needs a value, the value of the variable is retrieved, so saying "p" in that context is the same as saying "the value of variable p":

```
int *q = p;  // Copy the value of variable p into the variable q.
             // aka: copy p into q.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question, the term `p` is a pointer variable, and its value is a pointer to `i`, which is `i`'s address, also `&i`.

And for your question, I'd like to offer some fresh ideas about it. (I guess you are reading K.N.King's C programming: A Modern Approach).

When it comes to the questions about the difference between `pointer` and `pointer variable`, I'd say that it's truly quite confusing. But the first thing we should keep in mind is that in many programming language, **values** are always stored in **variables**. The **values** may vary, they may be integers, characters, addresses (we have discussed above about the difference between addresses and integer numbers), etc. For instance, to store an `int` number, we need an `int variable`. Similarly, to store a `pointer` (address) value, we need a `pointer variable`. So, `pointer` here is nothing more than an address and the pointer variable is just a variable that stores the value, which is an address.
The second thing is that it is actually not good to say that **"a pointer points to an object"**, it's not correct. The correct saying is that **"A pointer variable points to an object"**. And actually after we define a pointer variable `p`, we'd like to say **`p` points to the object**. And there is no problem with it. It is always the case that we should say that **A pointer variable points to an object.** However, another kind of saying is also common, that is **"A pointer to an object"**, e.g. "A pointer to `i`". In effect, this is just another saying of the **object's address**, and there is also no problem with it. But notice that we **didn't** specify the name of the pointer variable that stores the pointer (address) to the object.